# Class inheritance and importing -- python

Tags: python, class, python-import, multiple-inheritance

This may be a little lengthy but I am at a loss with importing my parent and child class.

I have a feeling I am getting my capitalization incorrect when applying the class names. I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: Student.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'age' and 'major'
```

Any help is much appreciated.

**StudentAdder.py** (Main)

```
import pickle
from sre_constants import SUCCESS
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from student import Student
from person import Person

#main method
def main():

    studentList = []
    #load the list from a pickle file
    with open("student.pickle", "rb") as f:
        studentList = pickle.load(f)

    #addStudent method to append Input to list
    def addStudent():
        name = "name"
        age = "age"
        major = "major"
        name = nameInput.get()
        age = ageInput.get()
        major = majorInput.get()
        studentList.append(Student(name, age, major))
        #save list to pickle file
        with open("student.pickle", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(studentList, f)

    #displays a success message upon adding a student
    def onClick():
        messagebox.showinfo("SUCCESS", "Student Added!")

    #create a GUI
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Add a Student")
    window.geometry("325x175")
  
    #create labels and text boxes for each value
    nameLabel = Label(window, text="Name:")
    ageLabel = Label(window, text="Age:")
    majorLabel = Label(window, text="Major:")

    nameInput = StringVar()
    ageInput = StringVar()
    majorInput = StringVar()

    #create grid for labels
    nameLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
    ageLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)
    majorLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)

    #create input boxes for each value
    nameInput = Entry(window, width = 25)
    ageInput = Entry(window, width = 25)
    majorInput = Entry(window, width = 25)

    #create grid for input boxes
    nameInput.grid(row=0, column=1)
    ageInput.grid(row=1, column=1)
    majorInput.grid(row=2, column=1)

    #create a save button to save the student -- binds commands to button
    saveButton = Button(window, text="Save", command= lambda: [addStudent(), onClick()])
    saveButton.grid(row=3, column=1)

    #create quit button
    quitButton = Button(window, text="Quit", command= window.destroy)
    quitButton.grid(row=4, column=1)

    #start the GUI
    window.mainloop()

    #print the list
    print()
    for student in studentList:
        print(student)

    print()

main()
```

**person.py** (Parent Class)

```
#create a parent class
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getAge(self):
        return self.age

    def setName(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def setAge(self, age):
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return "Person: " + self.name + " " + str(self.age)
```

**student.py** (Child Class)

```
from person import Person

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, major):
        Student(Person).__init__(self, name, age, major)
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.major = major

    def getMajor(self):
        return self.major

    def setMajor(self, major):
        self.major = major

    def __str__(self):
        return "Student: " + self.name + \
            ", Age: " + str(self.age) + \
            ", Major: " + self.major
```

Comment: Why are you calling `Student(Person).__init__(self, name, age, major)` inside `Student.__init__`? You probably want to call `super().__init__(name, age)` and then `self.major = major`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your mistake is this line in student.py:

```
Student(Person).__init__(self, name, age, major)
```

The code `Student(Person)` is trying to make a new instance of Student, but you are only passing one argument (`Person`) instead of the required three (`name`, `age` and `major`). That is why you see `missing 2 required positional arguments: 'age' and 'major'` in your error message.

However, it looks like you are actually trying to call the `__init__` method of the parent class. You would do that like this:

```
super().__init__(name, age)
```

Note that I did not specify the `major` argument, as the `Person` class does not accept this as a parameter. Also, the `__init__` method of the `Person` class already stores the `name` and `age` parameters, so you don't need to do that in `Student.__init__`. So you can change `Student.__init__` to be the following:

```
class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, major):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.major = major
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to depend on `Person.__init__`, you can leave out the `super()` call and set all the attributes yourself:

```
class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, major):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.major = major
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I did make the changes you suggested `super().__init__(name, age)` but I'm still seeing the TypeError. Maybe `studentList.append(Student(name, age, major))` is an issue? Or is that correct?

Comment: That part looks correct to me. Maybe you didn't save the file, or you are running an old version of the code, or something like that?

Comment: Oh god... you're right. All good. Thank you again!

Comment: Also, is the error message exactly the same, or is it slightly different? It's possible you may have a similar-looking but slightly different problem.

Comment: Ok, all good. Nice!

Comment: If this helped you, please mark my answer as the accepted answer. :)